# Is it possible to power a 3b+ and the display with the poe hat?

Tags: power, display, touchscreen, poe

For a project I would like to power the 3b+ and the official 7” touch display using the official POE hat.

I figured that I could connect the display board to the pi via the jumper wires to 5v and GND as usual, and power it the other way round. Would this work?

I already tried powering the display board using a USB cable connected to one of the pi USB ports, but that did not work.

Comment: If the answer provided resolved your issue, good practice to mark as ***answered*** to preclude other members revisiting it unecessarily.  Thanks- T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came around to try this. Simply connecting the 5V and ground pins from the display board to GPIO pin 4 and 6 worked.
I had to raise the GPIO pins (https://www.adafruit.com/product/2223 ) so they protruded from the POE hat.
This required to raise the POE header too.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact problem as you.  Found it was not possible due to the form factor of the Pi 3B+ when a PoE Hat affixed to it to fit in the "[Smarti Pi Touch](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/smartipi-touch)" case.  Used a [PoE Splitter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B074Y6M67F/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (£9.90 in VAT from Amazon.co.uk) as a workaround.  The power from the PoE switch is sufficient to drive both the Official 7" LCD Display *AND* the 3B+  Best of all, the door closes on the "Smarti Pi Touch case" ;-)

[image: PoE Splitter used to power both the 7" display and Pi]

Comment: Thanks @F1Linux, I have a POE splitter as well, so that would be my backup plan. But I liked the idea of having everything in one package, which is not the case when using a splitter. I was looking at the same case as you have, and was hoping the POE hat could fit in the large "SmartiPi Touch back cover".

Comment: The Smarti Pi Touchscreen cases now have an adjunct cover you can buy separately to hide all the bits sticking out of the back of it, but lacks ventilation.  Might be an option to to achieve your goal of keeping everything in a tidy package. I'd drill some holes in it this cover to get some air flow though as the 3B+'s run quite hot:  https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/smartipi-touch-back-cover?variant=21202189877331

Comment: Exactly, thats the one I meant. Good point about the ventilation holes.